# Can I reset the Blacksmith's crafting inventory?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Blacksmith seems to have reset his inventory upon leveling up, but now he always has the same stuff. Can I get a new list of items to craft? He only has a few rares and I would like to see a larger selection.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking - all of the blacksmith's items have random magic properties. He doesn't need multiples in the same level range.

Comment: @RavenDreamer He is however lacking several _types_ of gear, specifically in the rare category. For example, my wizard can make a rare book, rare boots but no option for a rare wand or rare hat for example.

Comment: @Resorath - I think there might be something else going on then. My wizard can make a rare belt, and that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're asking if you can reset him so that when you start training him again, he'll get a different set of recipes.

Even if you could reset him (which I don't believe you can do), this won't work. My wife and I both got in the beta. I just compared her blacksmith to mine, and except for the fact that I'd trained mine up a little bit further, we had exactly the same recipes. I'm pretty sure the list of recipes you get for him as you train him is fixed. Every time you spend some gold to train him, you unlock a few more recipes. So if you did somehow manage to reset him, you'd just have to work to re-unlock all of the recipes you've already unlocked.

If it is randomized, then it would be one heck of a coincidence that my wife and I unlocked the same set of recipes up though level 2 training.

Comment: Its quite possible that this is just 'beta' behavior. I wouldn't be surprised if it's different upon full release.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this IGN page about Blacksmith progression](http://www.ign.com/wikis/diablo-3/Blacksmith_Progression), the unlocked items for leveling up a blacksmith are predefined.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure (i don't have beta). BUT, i read that you get the recipes from monsters and (i guess) quests, to improve your BS list.

You are probably on beta, so, they can make changes that will NOT occur in the real thing. So becareful with this kind of stuff.

Good luck.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Although I have never seen anything like this, certain features are disabled in beta. But then does that mean everyone always starts with the same available crafting options?

Comment: @Resorath See: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blacksmith-plan/

Comment: Thanks Krazer . @Resorath more links: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3530214405